# R Vectorize: Assign values to each row, diff col based on col index for every row

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I have a matrix of A of 40000 rows and 9 cols and a vector B with 40000 items.
Each item in B is a number from 1 to 9. I want to assign the particular column in A corresponding to the item in B with 1.
Right now, I'm using a for  loop for it.

```
for(r in 1:40000){
   A[r,B[r]]=1
}
```

But is there a way to vectorize it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
A[cbind(1:nrow(A), B)] <- 1
```

Checking results with the OP's code

```
 for(r in 1:nrow(A1)){
  A1[r, B[r]] <- 1
  }
 identical(A, A1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Here we use a matrix that we created with `cbind`.  From `?"["`:

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- matrix(sample(1:40, 25*9, replace=TRUE), ncol=9)
B <- sample(1:9, 25, replace=TRUE)
A1 <- A
```